# Custom Drop Down Field Type Validation

Tags: fieldtypes, custom-fieldtype

I have a custom fieldtype that I have built in a plugin. I want to validate these fields inside of field settings when data is added. I saw there was a `getErrors` method in the model however I am unsure on how to post errors to this field settings page. Can anyone point me in the right direction for what method I should be doing this in so that you cant save unless these fields validate?

Thanks